# What is the chronological order of Dead Space media?

Tags: suggested-order, chronological-order, dead-space

I have played the first game and watched an animated film, *[Dead Space: Downfall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1267379/?ref_=nv_sr_1)*,  years ago. The film was a prequel to the game. Now, I understand, there are comics and even another animated film (at least) on top of the games I have not played yet.

What is the chronological order for the release of *Dead Space* properties? Is there a recommended viewing order as well so that I can understand the story as it was "meant" to be unfolded?

Comment: I suppose this would have the added effect of making all the media known to me as well.

Comment: Are these types of questions discouraged then, given the CVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the chronological order of events in all Dead Space media, from my memory and [this timeline on the Dead Space wiki](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline).

- *Dead Space: Martyr* (novel, 2010)
- *Dead Space: Catalyst* (novel, 2012)
- *Dead Space* (comics, 2008)
- *Dead Space: Downfall* (film, 2008; takes place at the same time as Extraction)
- *Dead Space: Extraction* (game and comics, 2009)
- *Dead Space* (game, 2008)
- *Dead Space: Salvage* (comics, 2010)
- *Dead Space: Aftermath* (film, 2011)
- *Dead Space* (mobile game, 2011)
- *Dead Space: Ignition* (game, 2011)
- *Dead Space 2* (game, 2011)
- *Dead Space 2: Severed* (DLC, 2011; takes place at the same time as Dead Space 2)
- *Dead Space: Liberation* (comics, 2013)
- *Dead Space 3* (game, 2013)
- *Dead Space 3: Awakened* (DLC, 2013)

In my opinion, either play/read/watch it all in chronological order, or by date of publication, which I've put in parentheses after each work. Order of publication is usually the way to go for most media, as that is how the creators "meant" them to be presented to you.

There are some plot points that are "spoiled" if you go the chronological route, but that mostly happens if you read works set prior to the events of *Dead Space* (the main game) before playing it, but since you have played it already I'd say you can go either way.